# How to extend the reach of the select_related function of Django Queryset so it includes the table related to a table related to the original table

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset, django-orm

This is what my models.py looks like

```
    class Branches(models.Model):
        def __str__(self):
            return self.location

        location = models.CharField(max_length=256, unique=True)


    class Daily_Infos(models.Model):
        class Meta:
            unique_together = ["date", "branch_id"]

        def __str__(self):
            return str(self.date) + " " + str(self.branch_id)

        branch_id = models.ForeignKey(Branches, related_name='daily_info', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        date = models.DateField()

    class Branch_Prices(models.Model):
        def __str__(self):
            return str(self.branch_id) + " " + str(self.menu_item_id) + " " + str(self.price)

        branch_id = models.ForeignKey(Branches, related_name='prices', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        menu_item_id = models.ForeignKey(Menu_Items, related_name='prices', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        price = models.FloatField()

    class Sold_Menu_Items(models.Model):
        def __str__(self):
            return str(self.branch_price_id) + " " + str(self.daily_info_id) + " " + str(self.quantity)

        daily_info_id = models.ForeignKey(Daily_Infos, related_name='sold_menu_items', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        branch_price_id = models.ForeignKey(Branch_Prices, related_name='sold_menu_items', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        quantity = models.IntegerField()

    class Menu_Items(models.Model):
        def __str__(self):
            return str(self.name) + " " + str(self.size)

        name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
        size = models.CharField(max_length=64)
        start_date = models.DateField()
        is_active = models.BooleanField()
```

In my views.py, I have this function:

```
def view_sold_items_all(request):
    sold_menu_items = Sold_Menu_Items.objects.select_related('branch_price_id','daily_info_id')
    refined_sold_menu_items = []
    for smi in raw_sold_menu_items:
        menu_item = []
        menu_item.append(smi.daily_info_id.date)
        menu_item.append(smi.quantity)
        menu_item.append(smi.branch_price_id.branch_id.location)
        menu_item.append(smi.branch_price_id.menu_item_id.name)
        menu_item.append(smi.branch_price_id.menu_item_id.size)

        refined_sold_menu_items.append(menu_item)
    return render(request, 'view_all.html', {
        'sold_items':refined_sold_menu_items
        })
```

Based on my understanding, the code below (which is in my views.py file) will allow Django to query my database only once.

```
sold_menu_items = Sold_Menu_Items.objects.select_related('branch_price_id','daily_info_id')
```

During the for loop, it will not keep querying the database for the two lines:

```
menu_item.append(smi.daily_info_id.date)
menu_item.append(smi.quantity)
```

However, for the other three appends, I think Django still queries the database because select_related does not cover that since it is not directly associated with the Sold_Menu_Items table.

My question is, how do I make my code more efficient? I was planning on having Django query the database only once so that in the three appends of the for loop, it will not need to keep querying my database. I was thinking that maybe I could use select_related a second time on the Branch_Prices table. However, I do not know how to do that and I do not even know if that is the right way to go about making my code more efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I was able to answer my own question. Is this the proper way to do it? I made some edits to my views.py.

```
def view_sold_items_all(request):
    raw_sold_menu_items = Sold_Menu_Items.objects.select_related(
        'daily_info_id',
        'branch_price_id__branch_id', 
        'branch_price_id__menu_item_id',
    )
    refined_sold_menu_items = []
    for smi in raw_sold_menu_items:
        menu_item = []
        menu_item.append(smi.daily_info_id.date)
        menu_item.append(smi.branch_price_id.branch_id.location)
        menu_item.append(smi.branch_price_id.menu_item_id.name)
        menu_item.append(smi.branch_price_id.menu_item_id.size)
        menu_item.append(smi.quantity)
        refined_sold_menu_items.append(menu_item)
    return render(request, 'view_all.html', {
        'sold_items':refined_sold_menu_items
        })
```